# Jupyter Notebook е открывает свой же скрипт: UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8')

Tags: python, кодировка, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Как спасти ipynb файл?! 
Сделала код в jupyter notebook, сохранила, пытаюсь открыть на другом компе тоже в Jupyter. Не открывается. Выдаёт ошибку "Unreadable Notebook in Jupyter: UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8')":

> Unreadable Notebook: C:\lda.ipynb UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'j\x1d\xc7\xbed,M\xac\x1e\xa0*1]\x8e\xe00\x9cd#\xc1\xba;#\x7fdm:\x14x\x95\x14j\x1a\x86\x07sn^ia\x00\xb55f\xb2\x06G\xaf\xd2\x85wHk\xeb\xbclp!\x01BB\xae\xaa\xa69.... и т.д

Что это за кодировка - не понятно, не считывает ни один онлайн-декодер. В любом другом текстовом notepad тоже не открывается.

Comment: Версии Python одинаковые?

Comment: если открыть блокнотом оттуда код нельзя "выцепить"?

Comment: Нет, он не открывается нигде в нормальном виде.. везде такая ерунда.